# Magento - After clicking place order, payment processing being done on checkout page rather then redirect for processing

Tags: magento, module, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

In Magento I want to achieve something as follows:

After clicking the place order button, I want the payment processing being done on checkout page, rather then redirecting for payment processing. Then it should redirect only after its completely processed to success page and in case of error should return back to payment section and no redirection should take place at all.

Please guide me on how to achieve this in Magento.

Comment: this totally depend on payment methods. some provide payment on website feature while some redirect you to their own page for payment. one of paypal method will allow you to pay on your own web feature.

Comment: I want to achieve this in my custom payment method. Please let me know where I can start from?

Comment: go through with http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-one--cms-23464. It has three parts read them all

Comment: I have gone through that tutorial. But its giving us an example/idea for that same redirect thing. I don't want that.

Comment: Instead of redirect I want the processing to be done on the same page and then I want to populate a light/fancy box with final payment processing url or in an iframe etc. which will redirect to success/error page accordingly.